# What type of valve do shock pumps use?

Tags: pump, schrader, shocks

Do all shock pumps use a schrader valve?  I've just taken a look at a couple of product listings and found no mention of the valve type.  I guess that might be to avoid people buying those pumps for regular tires after reading that they connect to schrader valves, but right now I'm trying to figure out what is correct for my new fork.

The fork description states that it has a schrader valve, and I was able to confirm that with my roady style hand pump, but obviously only top it up a tiny amount.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, very nearly all, if not all [shock pumps](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_0_10?url=search-alias=sporting&field-keywords=shock%20pump&sprefix=shock%20pump) certainly do use a schrader valve.

Comment: Cars use schrader valves too from what I can tell, is the presta valve only used in the bicycle domain?